# BigQuery: Use CAST, GROUP BY, and HAVING

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to use HAVING after a GROUP BY but I get this error:

> SELECT list expression references sales_order.SalesOrderDateTime
> which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [2:8]

The field is in the `SELECT` list, and `GROUP BY`, but it is part of a `CAST` because I do not want the timestamp part of the datetime.  It works without the `CAST` on another table where the format is already *YYYY-MM-DD*.  It really should work here as well.  Is there a way around this?

I tried using `STRING FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD'` but that does not work either.

```sql
SELECT 
  CAST(sales_order.SalesOrderDateTime AS DATE) as created_at,
  sales_order.SalesOrderNo as order_id,
  sales_order.SellToEmail as customer_email,
  sum(sales_order_item.OriginalPrice)*100 as total_amount_cents,
  max(sales_order.TotalDiscountAmount)*100 as discount_amount_cents
FROM `my_dw.external_datamart_1.SalesOrder_view` 
WHERE CAST(sales_order.SalesOrderDateTime AS DATE) >= '2022-01-01'
GROUP BY CAST(sales_order.SalesOrderDateTime AS DATE), sales_order.SalesOrderNo, sales_order.SellToEmail
-- This does not work with CAST
HAVING sum(sales_order_item.OriginalPrice) > max(sales_order.TotalDiscountAmount)
LIMIT 1000
)
```

A CTE works of course, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. But, can you try **group by 1, 2, 3** instead of using full expressions?

Comment: TY @Max Zolotenko.  I can confirm that GROUP BY 1,2,3 works!  The other way does not.  Feel free to post as an answer and I will mark it Accepted.

Comment: @MaxZolotenko, you may post your comment on the answer section so that the community can easily find the answer to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
group by 1,2,3
```

instead of using full expressions.

I face the same issue time to time in my complex queries. I think it's a bug and can be reported here https://issuetracker.google.com/